# jQuery appending overflow in div?

Tags: jquery

So I am trying to create a chat system, but am currently focusing on the user and not the actual interaction, but basically [here it is](http://s1527.mtchs.org/chat.html).

some issues include:

1. if you enter a value, you can repeatedly hit submit and it will cut off the animation whenever you did
2. after you submit value remains in textarea(i want it cleared)
3. when you submit too much into the div, the content ignores the div and ruins the positioning.

please help me. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For Issue 1 : Why can't you create a plugin for TypeWriting effect like this:

```
$.fn.teletype = function(opts){
var $this = this,
    defaults = {
        animDelay: 50,
    text:''
    },
    settings = $.extend(defaults, opts);

$.each(settings.text, function(i, letter){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $this.html($this.html() + letter);
    }, settings.animDelay * i);
});
}
```

So that you can create multiple instances and it would not affect the previous one. Once done, you can destroy that instance.

For Ex, you can call the above plugin like,

```
$('#container').teletype({
animDelay: 50,  
text: 'Text to be typed here.'
});
```